# I have been trying to deal with this issue for a while now, I am a newbie in shell programming, can anyone help me out?

Tags: bash, shell

(EDITED)

I have the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 3< lista.csv
read -u 3 header
nota1=0
id1=0
nota2=0
id2=0
nota3=0
id3=0
g=1
while [ "$g" -eq 1 ]
do
g=0
while IFS="," read -u 3 -r id nume prenume grupa seria nota
do
if [ "$nota" -gt "$nota1" ]
then
g=1
nota3="$nota2"
id3="$id2"
nota2="$nota1"
id2="$id1"
nota1="$nota"
id1="$id"
fi
done
done
while IFS=, read -u 3 -r id nume prenume grupa seria nota
do
    if [ "$id" -eq "$id1" ]; then
echo "Nume: $nume"
echo "Prenume: $prenume"
echo "Grupa: $grupa"
echo "Seria: $seria"
echo "Nota: $nota"
echo
    fi
done
while IFS=, read -u 3 -r id nume prenume grupa seria nota
do
    if [ "$id" -eq "$id2" ]; then
echo "Nume: $nume"
echo "Prenume: $prenume"
echo "Grupa: $grupa"
echo "Seria: $seria"
echo "Nota: $nota"
echo
    fi
done
while IFS=, read -u 3 -r id nume prenume grupa seria nota
do
    if [ "$id" -eq "$id3" ]; then
echo "Nume: $nume"
echo "Prenume: $prenume"
echo "Grupa: $grupa"
echo "Seria: $seria"
echo "Nota: $nota"
echo
    fi
done
```

I am supposed to find the top 3 highest values of the operand 'nota' and output the whole line.I know it's not the most space and time effective way, but I don't know how else I could do it.
My csv file looks somewhat like this:

```
id,nume,prenume,grupa,seria,nota

1,Ion,Andrada,1003,A,8

2,Simion,Raluca,1005,A,7

3,Gheorghita,Mihail,1009,B,5

4,Mihailescu,Georgina,1002,A,6
```

I have applied the necessary changes proposed, but the program still doesn't seem to work. when I execute it it doesn't let me input values to read. I have seen that some of you have suggested to try it in another programming language, but in this case it is not possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: I recommend learning and using python over bash script.

Comment: As the [bash tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) you used in your question instructs you to do - copy/paste your shell script(s) into https://shellcheck.net and fix the problems that tool tells you about before posting here if you still have a problem afterwards. Please also read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) to understand why you shouldn't be trying to use bash or any other shell for this task.

Comment: `nota3=nota2` sets `nota3` to the literal string `nota2`.  If you want to use the value of the variable, you want `nota3="$nota2"`.

Comment: FYI AWK is a mandatory POSIX tool so it's available on all Unix boxes and is the tool that the people who created Unix shell also created for shells to call to manipulate text. Get the book Effective AWK Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robbins to learn how to write awk scripts.

Comment: Missing `do` after the first `while`.

Comment: learning to use consistent indentations will go a long way towards improving the readability of your code while at the same time making it easier to debug these types of syntax issues

Comment: I have read your comments and did the necessary changes to the program, but I still have some issues, can you check it out again please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you only need to the 3 highest lines, you can try this `head` and `sort`

```
$ head -3 <(sort -t',' -nrk6 input_file)
1,Ion,Andrada,1003,A,8
2,Simion,Raluca,1005,A,7
4,Mihailescu,Georgina,1002,A,6
```